# How to ensure substrings are put back at the right index of a string after being removed initially in javascript?

Tags: javascript, replace, indexof

I have a string which looks like below

```
query = "I learned to =play the 'Ukulele' in 'Lebanon'."
```

As you can see, it has some special characters like `=`, `'` in this which I want to remove initially.

However anything I remove has to be put back eventually. So before removing, I must remember the index position of each occurrence of these special characters. So I wrote a code that stores the mapping information which contains the characters and their multiple indices. This is how it looks like

```
specialCharIndexMapping {
  ',': [],
  "'": [ 23, 31, 36, 44 ],
  '"': [],
  '=': [ 13 ],
  '>': [],
  '<': []
}
```

As you can see, single quote `'` has appeared at indices 23, 31, 26, 44 and equal to `=` has appeared at index 13.

Now I remove the special characters from the string

```
query = query.replace(/"/g,"").replace(/'/g,"").replace(/=/g,"").replace(/>/g,"").replace(/</g,"").replace(/,/g,"");
```

So now my query looks like below

```
query = I learned to play the Ukulele in Lebanon.
```

Now I need to put those special characters back into my string based on the index information. So this is what I do

```
for (char in specialCharIndexMapping) {
        if(specialCharIndexMapping[char] !== []) {
            charIndices = specialCharIndexMapping[char]
            for(i=0; i<charIndices.length; i++) {
                index = charIndices[i]
                //query = query.substr(0, index) + char + query.substr(index);
                query = query.slice(0, index) + char + query.slice(index);
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(query)
}
```

But the characters are put back at the wrong places. This is what my final string looks like

```
query = "I learned to =play the U'kulele 'in L'ebanon.'"
```

After spending some time, I realised it might be due to string getting shifted due to introduction of new characters. So subsequent indices won't hold true. So I tried doing something below

```
for (char in specialCharIndexMapping) {
        if(specialCharIndexMapping[char] !== []) {
            charIndices = specialCharIndexMapping[char]
            for(i=0; i<charIndices.length; i++) {
                if (i==0) {
                  index = charIndices[i]
                }
                else {
                    index = charIndices[i] -1
                }
                //query = query.substr(0, index) + char + query.substr(index);
                query = query.slice(0, index) + char + query.slice(index);
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(query)
}
```

I basically keep reducing the index position by 1 except the first replacement. This does take it much closer to the original string but it still is wrong. This is how it looks like now

```
query = "I learned to =play the U'kulele' in 'Lebanon'."
```

How do I ensure the special characters are replaced at appropriate places and I get the original string back?

Comment: You basically need to sort the indices, so that you can insert them in order.

Comment: You need to store the indexes during the phase where you remove them. Then you do the reverse, add them to their previous indices.

Comment: @Bergi So I should sort the values of each key in say ascending order and then do the replacement and then I am done?

Comment: @ChrisR could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @SouvikRay You'd need to sort all values of all keys together. The `=` needs to be inserted before the apostrophes in your example string, but of course for more complex examples they might be arbitrarily intermixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the code, hope it helps!
The key factor is to convert to an Array which lets you manipulate it better than a string.

```js
// !WARNING: This code uses ES6 (ECMA2015+) syntax
const query = "I learned to =play the 'Ukulele' in 'Lebanon'.";
const charToRemove = [',', "'", '"', '=', '>', '<'];

const foundPositions = []
// Loop over all letters and save their respective position and their character
const cleanedQuery = query.split('').map((char, index) => {
  if (charToRemove.includes(char)) {
    foundPositions.push([index, char]);
    // Return an empty string to remove the character
    return '';
  } else {
    return char;
  }
}).join('');

console.log('cleanedQuery', cleanedQuery);
console.log("savedPositions", foundPositions);

// Loop over found characters to put them back into place
const rebuiltQuery = foundPositions.reduce((acc, pair) => {
  const [
    index,
    char
  ] = pair;
  acc.splice(index, 0, char);
  return acc;
}, cleanedQuery.split('')).join('');

console.log("originalQuery", rebuiltQuery);
console.log('query and originalQuery are the same:', (query === rebuiltQuery).toString());
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Works with all the examples I have tried so far. Great work!